# Як перекласти "card drafting game" українською?

Tags: переклад, from-english, сленг

[Card drafting](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2984/closed-drafting) — концепція/механіка з карткових настільних ігор. Типовим прикладом гри з цією механікою є 7 Wonders. На [її сторінці](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81) у російській вікіпедії кажеться, что це "игра с технологией драфта" (української сторінки наразі немає). У розмовній мові я зустрічав вживання просто слова "драфт", а у [російськомовних](https://tesera.ru/user/ThunderWolf/thought/664680/) та [англомовних](https://www.bert.games/post/card-drafting) джерелах про нього мовиться як про механіку, а не "технологію". Google translate перекладає "[card drafting](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=uk&text=Card%20Drafting&op=translate)" як "складання картки", а "[card drafting game](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=uk&text=card%20drafting%20game&op=translate)" як "гра в складання карток", що взагалі не схоже на доречний переклад. Та навіть якщо "card drafting" умовитися перекладати як "драфт" (чи варто додавати "картковий"?), залишається питання — як перекладати "card drafting game" кажучи про *різновиди ігор*? Дослівно "ігри карткового драфту" — звучить занадто неприродньо.

Питання виникло за спроби перекласти з английської уривок "one of the most popular *card drafting* board games in the world" у контексті опису настільної гри 7 Wonders на сайті присвяченому настільним іграм з можливістю локалізації силами користувачів.

Comment: you can add posts in English or Ukrainian, posts in other languages will be deleted.

Comment: @Yola thanks for the answer! I can translate my post. Could you provide a link to page where this rule is published and where new users can read it? I was looking for it at ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, but this page is almost empty. BTW, is this rule related only to posts or comments as well?

Comment: @belkka, sorry for inconvenience. It was discussed [here](//area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25748) and [here](http://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4). But you are right that it's not easy to find that information :(.

Comment: Автор переклав запитання. Чи не варто зняти мінуси?

Answer (score -2):

## Карткові ігри з драфтом (card drafting games)

Це словосполучення можна побачити, наприклад, у каталозі українського Інтернет-магазину настільних ігор https://desktopgames.com.ua/ua/catalog/boardgames/draft/

[image: зображення частини веб-сторінки із заголовком "Карткові ігри з драфтом"]

Як на мене, цей варіант перекладу сприймається досить природньо.

## **Драфт або картковий драфт (card drafting)**

Вживання слова "драфт" можна знайти [в українській вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82) і [тут](https://zkan.com.ua/chomy/shho-take-draft-draft-i-constructed-konstrakted-v.html) (мається на увазі тип партії з одноіменною механікою).

Словосполучення "картковий драфт" можна [знайти](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%22) на таких сторінках (хоча, описи ігор в інтернет магазинах могли перекладатися послівно з английської чи російської):

- https://geekach.com.ua/ua/civ.-carta-impera-victoria-ukrainskoe-izdanie/
- https://m.facebook.com/commerce/products/1924754364226386/
- https://hod-konem.com/ua/p1330-seasons_sezoni
- https://nastolka.com.ua/uk/korolevstvo-krolikov

На російськомовних ресурсах можна [знайти](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%22) вживання словосополучення "карточный драфт", наприклад, [тут](https://tesera.ru/user/SadSido/thought/1189983/), [тут](https://hod-konem.com/p1330-seasons_sezoni) і [тут](https://www.lavkaigr.ru/shop/strategicheskie/skvoz-veka-novaia-istoriia-tsivilizatsii/)

Comment: If downvote, please, tell how can I improve the answer. I believe it can help others

Comment: Я трішки дурнуватий, але я не розумію: чому цю відповідь мінусують?

Comment: @Sasha, ну, наприклад, тому, що запитання позначене [tag:from-english], але чомусь і до запитання, і до відповіді штучно притягнуті джерела, які нам розповідають про переклад з англійської на якийсь північний діалект староболгарської. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135221/discussion-on-answer-by-belkka---card-drafting-game-).